# How to iterate all records that are within the current year? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to iterate all records from database and sum the value of a column, but only for this year.

For example, they ask: "Sum all the purchases that have a user for 1 year."

How I can do that in rails? Rails? Has some method to provide me this task?

For example, something like this:

```
current_user.purchases.each do |purchase|
  total_purchase += purchase.amount.to_i*purchase.product.price.to_f
end
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: `Sum all the purchases that have a user for 1 year.`

It sounds more like you need to sum all purchases made by users that are one year or older.

Comment: @toolz Only for one year. All purchases that have a user for only 2014 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

provided that purchases are a has_many relation to User, and there is an appropriate date field, you could use

```
total_purchase = 0
current_user.purchases.where('date_field > ?', Time.now.beginning_of_year).each do |purchase|
  total_purchase += purchase.amount.to_f * purchase.product.price.to_f
end
```

or if you want to use last year you could alter the where clause:
`where(date_field: 1.year.ago.beginning_of_year..Time.now.beginning_of_year)`

if `product` has a `belongs_to` relation to `purchase`, consider using `.includes(:product)` to limit your db queries.

Comment: consider studying the  relevant guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html